# Database system checksumming to prevent network corruption not caught by TCP checksumming

Tags: corruption, database-agnostic, data-integrity, tcpip, checksum

Since TCP checksumming is [not sufficient to detect/prevent all corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830206/can-a-tcp-checksum-fail-to-detect-an-error-if-yes-how-is-this-dealt-with), do modern database systems (e.g. SQL Server, MariaDB / MySQL, Oracle, etc.) use any additional checksumming of network traffic as part of their client/server protocol?

I did some searching but wasn't finding anything which made me wonder if perhaps they don't and just roll the dice.

Got a good answer on Oracle. Would like to hear about SQL Server and MariaDB  / MySQL as well.

Comment: I wonder if SSL/TLS offers more error checking there.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a variety of encryption and integrity features that are a part of its network protocols.

See [Configuring Encryption and Integrity Parameters Using Oracle Net Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/asoconfg.htm#DBSEG9599) in section 13 Configuring Oracle Database Network Encryption and Data Integrity of the Oracle Database Security Guide.

> [image: Integrity]